# While i am running the code below i am getting the adapter error,i tried solving it by seeing yt videos ....still its not working

Tags: android

While i am running the code below i am getting the adapter error,i tried solving it by seeing youtube videos ....still its not working ,its showing that adapter is abstract and so the error is there.which i have attached below.plz give the most relevent solution to this problem.

this is my GridAdapter.java code

```
public class GridAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GridAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    List<String>titles;
    List<Integer>images;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public GridAdapter(Context context,List<String>titles,List<Integer>images){
        this.titles = titles;
        this.images = images;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

  
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.intoduction,parent,false);

        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.titles.setText(titles.get(position));
        holder.images.setImageResource(images.get(position));

    }

    
    public int getItemCount() {
        return titles.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView titles;
        ImageView images;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            titles = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView15);
            images = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
        }
    }
}
```

this is my MainActivity2.java code

```
public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {
    RecyclerView recycleview1;
    List<String> titles;
    List<Integer>images;
    Adapter GridAdapter;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.intropage);
        recycleview1 = findViewById(R.id.recycleview1);

        titles = new ArrayList<>();
        images = new ArrayList<>();

        titles.add("first item");
        titles.add("second item");
        titles.add("third item");
        titles.add("fourth item");

        images.add(R.drawable.bheeshma);
        images.add(R.drawable.sadak2);
        images.add(R.drawable.tanhaji);
        images.add(R.drawable.thappad);

        GridAdapter =  **new Adapter(this,titles,images);**

        GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new 
        GridLayoutManager(this,2,GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false);
        recycleview1.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
        recycleview1.setAdapter(**GridAdapter**);




    }



}
```

this is the error i am getting

```
Adapter is abstract; cannot be instantiated
        GridAdapter =  new Adapter(this,titles,images);
```

Comment: Well, shouldn't it be `new GridAdapter(this,titles,images);` ?  Also, please don't give a variable the exact same name (`GridAdapter`) as a class.

Comment: i tried the suggestion suggested by u ........still its giving me an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using class name as variable name and the adapter you are using is of type GridAdapter(not Adapter).
Make these changes in MainActivity2 file.

```
GridAdapter adapter;
adapter=new GridAdapter(this,titles,images);
recycleview1.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't give any vairiable name for GridAdapter class.That's why you are getting this error.
First you have to declare it globally like
`GridAdapter gridAdapter;`

and then you should instantiate inside you onCreate() method like

```
 gridAdapter = new GridAdapter(this,titles,images);
```

this will be the solution for your problem.